# Windows 10 vm stopped working afther I installed docker

Tags: virtual-machine

I'm using virtual box and since I installed Docker in my pc, my windows 10 vm stopped working. I've uninstalled everything related to Docker and I've tried to fix it by unchecking the Hyper-V option in programs and features.

edit: I also tried to reinstall my vm.

Answer (score 0):

Manage to fixe it, had to uncheck the Virtual Machine Platform option in programs and features